# How to test my Deck class in Java

Tags: java, blackjack

I would like to print my ArrayList FullDeckArray to see if my Deck has all 52 cards and values.

This is my Card and Deck Classes below

```
package blackjack;

/**
 *
 * @author mvisser
 */
public class Card 
{

   private int rank;
   private int suit;

   public String tostring(Card card1)
   {

      String result = "";

      if (rank == 1) {
          result = "Ace";
      }
      if (rank == 2) {
          result = "Two";    
      }
      if (rank == 3) {
          result = "Three";

      }
      if (rank == 4) {
          result = "Four";   
      }
      if (rank == 5) {
          result = "Five";

      }
      if (rank == 6) {
          result = "Six";

      }
      if (rank == 7) {
          result = "Seven";

      }
      if (rank == 8) {
         result = "Eight";      
      }
      if (rank == 9) {
         result = "Nine";  
      }
      if (rank == 10) {
         result = "Ten";     
      }
      if (rank == 11) {
         result = "Jack";     
      }
      if (rank == 12) {
            result = "Queen";   
      }
      if (rank == 13) {
            result = "King";     
      }
      if (suit == 1) {
          result = result + " of Clubs ";
      }
      if (suit == 2) {
         result = result + " of Diamonds ";
      }
      if (suit == 3) {
          result = result + " of Hearts ";
      }
      if (suit == 4) {
          result = result + " of Spades ";
      }

      return result;

   }

   public Card(int rank, int suit) 
   {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;    
   }
}
```

As you can see in my Deck Class I hava a ArrayList FullDeckArray and all I want to do is
   print it out so see what value is bringing back

```
public class Deck 
{
//     private Card[][] fullDeck = new Card[0][0];
     private Random shuffle = new Random();
     public ArrayList<Card> FullDeckArray = new ArrayList<Card>();

//     private int numberOfCards = 52;

   public Deck()
   {


    for (int rank = 1; rank <= 13; rank++) {

            for (int suit = 1; suit <= 4; suit++)
            {
               FullDeckArray.add(new Card(rank, suit));


            }
        }
   }        

    public void shuffle() {
        Collections.shuffle(FullDeckArray);   
    }

    public Card DrawCard() {
        int cardPosition = shuffle.nextInt(FullDeckArray.size()+1);
        return FullDeckArray.remove(cardPosition);
    }

     public int TotalCards() {
            return FullDeckArray.size();
     }

     public void test() {
            System.out.println( ArrayList<Card>( FullDeckArray ) );
     }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(FullDeckArray);` ?

Comment: Hi assylias.  I cant get it printing.  I tried printing in my Deck class but display nothing.  But I dnt know how to call my array in my method(BlackJackGame) to print it out.  I am getting so dam confused.  but thank you for helping me

Comment: @user1798555 And remove `Card card1` in toString(Card card1). That will instantly fix the output.

Comment: I have removed the Card card1.  but all I get [blackjack.Card@1d9dc39, blackjack.Card@93dcd.  then someone said I must use return result.getClass().getName()+ "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode()); in my toString.  but I still get the same output

Answer (score 1):

I would use enums, and with the `enum.values()` method, you can easily loop through all values of the enumeration.

```
public class Card {
    public enum Rank { 
        ACE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING;
        public String toString() {
            switch(this) {
            case ACE: return "Ace";
            case TWO: return "Two";
            case THREE: return "Three";
            case FOUR: return "Four";
            case FIVE: return "Five";
            case SIX: return "Six";
            case SEVEN: return "Seven";
            case EIGHT: return "Eight";
            case NINE: return "Nine";
            case TEN: return "Ten";
            case JACK: return "Jack";
            case QUEEN: return "Queen";
            case KING: return "King";
            default: return "ERROR: no valid rank"; 
            }
        }
    }
    public enum Suit { 
        CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES;
        public String toString() {
            switch(this) {
            case CLUBS: return "Clubs";
            case DIAMONDS: return "Diamonds";
            case HEARTS: return "Hearts";
            case SPADES: return "Spades";
            default: return "ERROR: no valid suit";
            }
        }
    }
    private Rank rank;
    private Suit suit;

    public Card(Rank rank, Suit suit) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return rank.toString() + " of " + suit.toString();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (!(other instanceof Card)) return false;
        Card card = (Card) other;
        if (card.rank == this.rank && card.suit == this.suit) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

while in your deck class, you add all cards with this simple loop:

```
public void fill() {
    for (Rank rank : Card.Rank.values()) {
        for (Suit suit : Card.Suit.values()) {
            Card card = new Card(rank, suit)
            cards.add(card);
            System.out.println(card.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

The rest of your deck class, you can maintain.

If you want to check for the cards being only added once, you can use a HashSet, as in a set, Objects can only occur once (but you need the `equals()` method):

```
HashSet<Card> set = new HashSet<Card>(cards);
cards = new ArrayList<Card>(set);
```

After that, you can check size with 'cards.size()'.

Update: Here's some code for evading the usage of Arrays in Card and for evading enums:

```
public class Deck {
    private Random shuffle = new Random();
    public ArrayList<Card> fullDeck = new ArrayList<Card>();

    public Deck() {
        for (int rank = 1; rank <= 13; rank++) {
            for (int suit = 1; suit <= 4; suit++) {
                fullDeck.add(new Card(rank, suit));
            }
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        String deckOutput = "";
        for (Card card : fullDeck) {
            deckOutput += card.toString() + "\n";
        }
        System.out.println(deckOutput);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deck deck = new Deck();
        deck.print();
    }
}
```

And for Card, use this:

```
public class Card {
    private int rank;
    private int suit;

    public Card(int rank, int suit) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String Srank = "", Ssuit = "";
        switch(rank) {
            case 1: Srank = "Ace"; break;
            case 2: Srank = "Two"; break;
            case 3: Srank = "Three"; break;
            case 4: Srank = "Four"; break;
            case 5: Srank = "Five"; break;
            case 6: Srank = "Six"; break;
            case 7: Srank = "Seven"; break;
            case 8: Srank = "Eight"; break;
            case 9: Srank = "Nine"; break;
            case 10: Srank = "Ten"; break;
            case 11: Srank = "Jack"; break;
            case 12: Srank = "Queen"; break;
            case 13: Srank = "King"; break;
        }
        switch(suit) {
            case 1: Ssuit = "Clubs"; break;
            case 2: Ssuit = "Diamonds"; break;
            case 3: Ssuit = "Hearts"; break;
            case 4: Ssuit = "Spades"; break;
        }
        return Srank + " of " + Ssuit;
    }
}
```

To test, you can still use the HashMap/ArrayList method stated above (only if you implement an equals method in Card as well) and check with the `fulldeck.size()` if there are 52 cards (which will be all different, because of the HashMap).

Comment: Hi Christiaan, I would like to use enums but I cant so thats why I am having problems

Comment: @user1798555 What problems? If you copy/paste above code, it should work just fine. And why can't/aren't you allowed to use enums?

Comment: My project says you cant use Arrays and enums in Card Class.

Comment: @user1798555 And in the deck class you can? In that case I would work around that by declaring the enums in the Deck class. You can also replace the enums by Arrays which you fill manually.

Comment: I cant use enums at all but I can use arrays in my Deck class.  but I thought I will just create an arrya list so that it will be easier to shuffle the collections

Comment: @user1798555 see my addition. I evaded the use of enums/arrays in Card, this will work perfectly for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
public class DeckTest{
    public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println(new Deck().FullDeckArray);
    }
}
```

Your `Card` class should be like below code

```
 public class Card 
    {

       private int rank;
       private int suit;


       public String tostring()
       {

          String result = "";

          if (rank == 1) {
              result = "Ace";
          }
          if (rank == 2) {
              result = "Two";    
          }
          if (rank == 3) {
              result = "Three";

          }
          if (rank == 4) {
              result = "Four";   
          }
          if (rank == 5) {
              result = "Five";

          }
          if (rank == 6) {
              result = "Six";

          }
          if (rank == 7) {
              result = "Seven";

          }
          if (rank == 8) {
             result = "Eight";      
          }
          if (rank == 9) {
             result = "Nine";  
          }
          if (rank == 10) {
             result = "Ten";     
          }
          if (rank == 11) {
             result = "Jack";     
          }
          if (rank == 12) {
                result = "Queen";   
          }
          if (rank == 13) {
                result = "King";     
          }
          if (suit == 1) {
              result = result + " of Clubs ";
          }
          if (suit == 2) {
             result = result + " of Diamonds ";
          }
          if (suit == 3) {
              result = result + " of Hearts ";
          }
          if (suit == 4) {
              result = result + " of Spades ";
          }

          return result;

       }

       public Card(int rank, int suit) 
       {
            this.rank = rank;
            this.suit = suit;    
       }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Bhavik Thank you for your answer.  I got it printing but its seems like my ArrayList is not working because its only printing out [blackjack.Card@112f614, blackjack.Card@1d9dc39........ continues.  How can I print out Ace of Clubs 
Ace of Diamonds 
Ace of Hearts 
Ace of Spades 
Two of Clubs 
Two of Diamonds 
Two of Hearts ...... continues

Comment: I think you should change `toString` method of `Card` class as I updated in the answer.

Comment: I have changed my card class return result.getClass().toString();.  And also changed my main method  System.out.println(new Deck().FullDeckArray); but still get the same answer

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:  static and dynamic testing.  Static is simpler and less prone to error, but it cannot be an action performed for any other purpose other than to simply verify that this part of your program works properly before moving on with the rest.  Dynamic testing is slightly more complicated, but you can test a deck whenever you need to (for when the user modifies the deck in some fashion and you must validate it).

### Static testing

The static testing method and the simplest way to do this would be to print out all the cards in a deck and verify it manually.  To do that, you would first have to make an addition and a correction.  First, you should modify the signature of your `tostring` method in your `Card` class to be "`toString()`" without parameters.  This overrides the object method `toString()` which automatically converts an object to a String.  Second, you need to override `toString()` in your `Deck` class:

```
@Override
public void toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(Card card : FullDeckArray) {
        sb.append(card);  // calls Card class's toString() method automatically.
        sb.append('\n');  // newline character after each card
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Now all you have to do is use Deck's toString() method.

```
public void test() {
    System.out.println(this);  // calls Deck class's toString() method automatically
}
```

### Dyanmic testing

Testing it dynamically is a little more complicated, but not that much.  To test this, how would you go about doing it manually?  You'd look for missing cards or duplicates.  A good way to test such things are Sets.  But before you can use Sets, you must first override `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods to redefine how a Card class is considered unique.  A card is only equal to another if both rank and suit match.

So add these to your Card class:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + rank;
    result = prime * result + suit;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Card other = (Card) obj;
    if (rank != other.rank)
        return false;
    if (suit != other.suit)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Now that we have that, we proceed with the actual logic.  A simple test would go something like this:

```
For each card in your deck
    If card is not in set
        Add card to set
    Else
        Flag not valid!  Duplicate card!

If set does not have exactly 52 cards
    Flag not valid!  Extra or missing cards!
```

So it naturally flows that the the code would then be:

```
  public boolean test() {
      boolean valid = true;
      Set<Card> cardSet = new HashSet<Card>();
      for(Card card : FullDeckArray) {
          if(!cardSet.contains(card)) {
              cardSet.add(card);
          } else {
              valid = false;
          }
      }
      if(cardSet.size() != 52) {
         valid = false;
      }
      return valid;
  }
```

Also, [you should look here for using enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).  In addition to making code more readable, it also allows you to add methods like a class, and like a class, add `toString()` method.  Also see [jUnit](http://www.junit.org/) for a decent testing library for Java.

Answer (score 0):

you should override your tostring method like:

```
@override
public String toString(Card card1){
.....
}
```

and should just pass the arraylist name to System.out.println(). there is no need for type of the array list.

hope this helps...

Comment: The overriden method's signature you defined is wrong, Refer my answer for more explaination.

Comment: i was merely making a suggestion on using override citing the code mentioned in the question itself and yes i agree his code can be written in a better way.